# Не работает регулярное выражение на странице

Tags: php

Есть код

```
<div itemprop="description" class="tekst-opisaniya clearfix">
    Описание
</div>
```

Мне необходимо выбрать содержимое внутри блока (текст)
Делаю такую регулярку на php

```
'/<div itemprop="description" class="tekst-opisaniya clearfix">(.+?)<\/div>/iu'
```

Но увы ничего не находит. Хотя на странице другие элементы отлично выбираются регулярками. То есть код есть, но регулярка не хочет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить модификатор поведения "s", чтобы точка захватывала перенос строки

```
'/<div itemprop="description" class="tekst-opisaniya clearfix">(.+?)<\/div>/ius'
```

На вкладке "preg_match_all" видно, что так текст будет захвачен. [Ссылка](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/tgc)